# Web API status code 500 C# when adding a HttpGet

Tags: c#, .net, rest

I am creating a Web API that will work with some other scripts and I have a HttpGet. As I don't know what else for it to be that will invoke a delegate in all items and when I go to test the API, I get a http 500 status code.

The code for this function is:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<DownloadEventItem>>> GetItemsInvoke()
{
    if (_context.Items == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    foreach (DownloadEventItem item in _context.Items.ToList())
    {
        item.InvokeEvent();
    }

    return await _context.Items.ToListAsync();
}
```

It doesn't need to return the list of items, however I can't think of how to actually do this, nor do I know what to look for online.

But what it should to is invoke each item in the database of the API all the other functions worked, just when I added this would it throw error 500.

If there is a way to perform something like this that would be great as I need to create more of these methods to add a method to the API from a different script and invoke from a browser extension

Comment: 500 is the code for "Internal Server Error". Find the error.

Comment: A GET is when a HTTP Request has no body (the context) while a PUT is when the HTTP Request has a body.  It looks like your request is download items which means there should be a body and you should be using a PUT.

Comment: So i dont get the error now however it looks as though it is skipping the invoke in the foreach it it just isnt ittereating at all ill see if i can add someway to debug it

Comment: it turns out that the HttpPut where it invokes the event works however just for testing i have it to just change the string in the json and it works when i return the item in the put request however when i use the get request it still has the same data as the post request set it to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by using HttpPost instead the code now looks like

```
[HttpPost("Invoke")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<DownloadEventItem>>> 
InvokeItems(string url, string cmd, string fromEmail, string toEmail, string serverName)
{
    cmd = "mono ServerReport.exe";
    if (_context.Items.ToList().Count < 1)
    {
        return Problem("No Event Item set");
    }

    string result = "Command Not Executed";

    foreach (DownloadEventItem item in _context.Items.ToList())
    {
        item.SetUrl(url);
        item.fromEmail = fromEmail;
        item.toEmail = toEmail;
        item.serverName = serverName;
        if (item.url != url)
        {
            return BadRequest("url not satisfiable");
        }
        RunCommandOnServer(cmd);
    }
    return Ok(result);
}
```

Comment: `_context.Items.ToList()` loads the entire table in memory when you only wanted to count the records. That's a serious bug. Use `_context.Items.Any()` or `_context.Items.AsQueryable().Any()` instead. EF Core will generate a query that returns `true` if there's any item. `.Items.Count()` will generate `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Items` which, while *not* loading the entire table, still tries to count all the rows

Comment: Oh i see i kind of forgot i had it on 2 instances instead of caching it in a variable but it would make more sense to do it that way even over caching as i only need to iterate through once thank you

Comment: If you want to reuse the data, what's the point of calling `Items.ToList()` twice? Just store the result of the first call in a variable and iterate over it.